# Google Cloud Cron failed php laravel but working when I put it in url

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, cron

Google Cloud Cron failed php laravel but working when I put it in url.

also I have app.yaml beside cron.yaml

app.yaml code

```
runtime: php72
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

[image]